# Java Tomcat переход с ip на домен

Tags: java, tomcat, vds

Я купил вдс сервер и установил на нем Tomcat. на вдс есть ip и домен (которые вроде привязан к этому ip) Кинул свой проект в webapps.

Если я зайду на

```
http://xxx.xxxx.xxxx:8080/testproject
```

то все норм. Но как мне поменять  `xxx.xxxx.xxxx:8080` на домен?

То есть чтоб получить свой проект по ссылке

```
http://mydomain.ru/testproject
```

Пробовал такое решение:

В conf/server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

8080 поменять на 80

И добавить этот код в тег Engine

```
<Host name="mydomain.com" appBase="webapps">
                    <Context
                      path=""
                      docBase="testproject"
                      reloadable="true"
                    />
</Host>
```

но чет ничего не сработало...

Answer (score 1):

Если домен локальный то надо прописать в hosts `xxx.xxxx.xxxx:8080 mydomain.com`, а если домен публичный нужно прописать нужный вам ip у регистратора домена.

Нужно настроить mod_proxy в Apache и настроить VirtualHost так как вам необходимо.
Вот пример:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/test"

        ServerName      mydomain.com
        ServerAlias     www.mydomain.com

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia full

        <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        ProxyPass / http://xxx.xxxx.xxxx:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx.xxxx.xxxx:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Вот тут можно почитать поподробнее [УСТАНОВКА HTTP-СЕРВЕРА APACHE КАК ОБРАТНОГО ПРОКСИ С ПОМОЩЬЮ MOD_PROXY](https://www.8host.com/blog/ustanovka-http-servera-apache-kak-obratnogo-proksi-s-pomoshhyu-mod_proxy/)

Comment: Он публичный. И вроде ip уже к нему привязан.  Но при заходе на mydomain.ru кидает на страницу Apache2 ubuntu default page

Comment: Очевидно что на 80 порту поднят Apache, вам следует в Apache настроить проксирование (mod_proxy) на ваш ip:port. Дополню ответ.